# cannot call firebird stored procedure from php

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, firebird

I have a firebird stored procedure sp_clinic_id that returns a string. It compiles and executes fine. The Sp has a suspend in its body.

So I used `select out1 from sp_clinic_id()` to call the procedure from php pdo.

Here's the code:

```
$sqlproc = "select out1 from SP_CLINIC_ID()";

// execute the stored procedure
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sqlproc);
$stmt->execute();
```

Instead of returning a prepared statement, pdo->prepare is returning false.

The error is "Dynamic Sql Error -104. Token Unknown". Since the procedure compiles and executes fine in firebird, I cannot understand why I'm getting a Dynamic Sql error.

Here is the stored procedure definition:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CLINIC_ID
RETURNS(
  MAXID VARCHAR(10))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE temp_char CHAR(10);
DECLARE VARIABLE temp_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  /* Procedure body */

  select MAX(CLINIC_id) from COVER_SHEET into MAXID;

  select SUBSTRING(:MAXID from 4 for CHAR_LENGTH(:MAXID)) 
  from rdb$database into temp_char ;

  select cast(:temp_char as NUMERIC) from rdb$database into temp_id;

  temp_id = temp_id + 1;

   if ( temp_id < 10) THEN
  BEGIN
    maxid = 'REG000000'|| temp_id;
  END

  else if ( temp_id < 100) THEN
  begin
  maxid = 'REG00000'|| temp_id;
  end  


  else if ( temp_id < 1000) THEN
  begin
  maxid = 'REG0000'|| temp_id;
  end  

  else if ( temp_id < 10000) THEN
  begin
  maxid = 'REG000'|| temp_id;
  end  

  ELSE if ( temp_id < 100000 ) THEN
  begin
  maxid = 'REG00'|| temp_id;
  end  

  ELSE if ( temp_id < 1000000) THEN
  begin
  maxid = 'REG0'|| temp_id;
  end  

  ELSE if ( temp_id < 10000000) THEN
  begin
  maxid = 'REG'|| temp_id;
  end  

  SUSPEND;
END;
```

Comment: Does the `stmt` have `open` method? If yes then use that instead of `execute`.

Comment: Thank you. I will try open. But it doesn't progress to that point. The prepare fails.

Comment: Can you show the definition of the stored procedure?

Comment: I think the problem is not in the procedure. If you execute from  SQL should be without brackets like `select out1 from SP_CLINIC_ID`. I think the problem is in PHP `prepare`.

Answer (score 1):

The return parameter's name is `MAXID` not `out1` as in your statement, so try

```
$sqlproc = "select MAXID from SP_CLINIC_ID";
```

Comment: ain, I tried this. Now the error is: Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => -204 [2] => Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 Table unknown SP_CLINIC_ID At line 1, column 19 ) 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: Try does using `PDO->query("select MAXID from SP_CLINIC_ID");` make any difference, ie don't use prepared statement this time.

Comment: It's the same  -204 Table Unknown error. If I use with brackets, it is -104 Token Unknown error

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

1. Yous SQL statement should be without parenthesis after procedure name, if the procedure does not expects any parameters.
2. Your procedure returns MAXID parameter, but you ask for OUT1.

So, an adjusted statement will be: `select maxid from sp_clinic_id`

A good idea is to try first statements in an SQL tool before pushing them in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

[**Calling a stored procedure with an output parameter**](http://php.net/manual/bg/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

> **If the database driver supports it**, you may also bind parameters for
>   output as well as input. Output parameters are typically used to
>   retrieve values from stored procedures. Output parameters are slightly
>   more complex to use than input parameters, in that you must know how
>   large a given parameter might be when you bind it. If the value turns
>   out to be larger than the size you suggested, an error is raised.
>
> Example #4 Calling a stored procedure with an output parameter
>
> ```
> <?php
>  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL sp_returns_string(?)");
>  $stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 
>
>  // call the stored procedure $stmt->execute();
>
>  print "procedure returned $return_value\n"; ?>
> ```

Comment: I tried using without brackets. But now, the error is Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => -204 [2] => Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 Table unknown SP_CLINIC_ID At line 1, column 18 ) 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: I tried the ? placeholder. Now the error is:Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => -204 [2] => Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -204 Procedure unknown SP_CLINIC_ID At line 1, column 18 ) 
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Comment: Ok. I changed my answer.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this issue? I'm stuck. I cannot get the prepare to work.

Comment: @SLakshmi Show the code of your stored procedure, right now we don't know what it's signature really is.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CLINIC_ID
RETURNS(
  MAXID VARCHAR(10))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE temp_char CHAR(10);
DECLARE VARIABLE temp_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  /* Procedure body */

  select MAX(CLINIC_id) from COVER_SHEET into MAXID;

  select SUBSTRING(:MAXID from 4 for CHAR_LENGTH(:MAXID)) 
  from rdb$database into temp_char ;
  
  select cast(:temp_char as NUMERIC) from rdb$database into temp_id;
  
  temp_id = temp_id + 1;
  
   if ( temp_id < 10) THEN
  BEGIN
   maxid = 'REG000000'|| temp_id;
  END

Comment: else if ( temp_id < 100) THEN
  begin
  maxid = 'REG00000'|| temp_id;
  end  

  
  SUSPEND;
END;

Comment: sorry ain. When I added the comment, the formatting was lost. I don't know how to post a comment with the formatting intact,

Answer (score 0):

when i tried to install the firebird and check, when i was giving without the page_size i am getting error like the below

**Dynamic SQL Error - Error code 104**

CREATE DATABASE 'f:\firebird_db\test.fdb' page_size 8192; //no error

CREATE DATABASE 'f:\firebird_db\test1.fdb'; //giving error

user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';

I have a clarification, can you manipulate other database operations, like simply getting the rows from the table, etc..,[image]

So fixing a page size can help you,

Comment: Please do not paste images when you can copy all the text and paste it here.